# Refreshing/Reload Angular 2 Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, model-view-controller, page-refresh

I'm new to angular 2.
I'm currently developing a huge web app with a lot of routes and sub-routes.
working with Web API.
the main problem in my app is when the user is log-in.im creating a JWT token and save it on sessionStorage and with guard I can keep the user session. but I miss something if the user fills a huge form and get a huge page with a lot of information base on his form when he refreshing the page, all of the data I manage to save in the service is gone.

How can I handle user refresh/reload pages? without losing the data

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Angular **LocalStorage**. Here's a link that might help you: [Angular 2 LocalStorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-localstorage)

Comment: consider this but ever a time when the user fills a form, ill need to save a huge object in local storage, and then when he reloads the page I need to read from that? Is it normal?

Comment: It is used a lot in this cases, and as I understood, you're storing string values? That shouldn't be a lot, but you can always try it for your application and test the performance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes, I create a web storage service that handles all thing of the sets gets data from the local storage/session storage. but now every reload I need to check on every ngOninit if there is stuff relevant to local storage? I think it's to much mass, there is any way to save "check-in "  on the last page to reload? cache handle?

Answer (score 0):

Update

I just make a webstorage. service that will handle all of the saving/removing data+stingefy necessary objects to and from session storage and local storage.
I'm still working on it but this is the idea.

```js
import { decode } from 'jwt-decode';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WebStorageService {
  constructor() {}

  public setData(key: string, data: any) {
    let encodedData = window.btoa(JSON.stringify(data));
    localStorage.setItem(key, encodedData);
  }
  public getData(key: string) {
    let encodedString = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return JSON.parse(window.atob(encodedString));
  }

  public removeData(key: string) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }
}
```